# Flutter google Analytics document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics

is there any documentation about adding flutter analytics to flutter?

why flutter is not on the listed platforms?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this link ->
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview/

You have to add the GoogleService-Info.plist file individually for both android and ios